# What might be causing horizontal lines on an early 2006 iMac?

Tags: display, imac

I picked up an early iMac, Early 2006 "Core Duo" 2.0 (4,1) - MA199 (aka A1173) - and it has horizontal lines on the screen:

[image: Photo fo screen showing horizontal line]

The seller showed pictures of the screen before shipping it to me and there were no lines. When I received the iMac, I can tell from how it was packed it would have received a lot of hard hits as it was not well padded and the box was very banged up.

The lines are varying in that sometimes there's a lot of them and sometimes there's just a few. I suspect this is a hardware issue (video adapter going bad, bad VRAM, etc.) but before I conclude that, I'm wondering if there are any steps I can take to rule any other causes out?

Comment: [Take a screenshot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361). If the lines do not appear in the image, then it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lines are not consistant, then it is *unlikely* to be an LED screen issue. This is because any "loose", or poor, connections, due to partial delamination, *tend* to be consistant, and not vary.

However, it might be possible to verify whether it is an LED screen issue, or not, by applying a little (local) pressure the border of the LED screen<sup>1</sup>, at either end of the line. If (when you press) the line goes, then there is likely to be a suspect contact.

As a side note: this isn't a foolproof method as no amount of pressure would temporarily fix a *corroded* contact. Nevertheless, a corroded contact would result in consistant lines across the screen and not change their location nor number

If the line is not due to a loose connection at the edge of the screen, then possible GPU issues are likely, and a reballing, or reflow, may be required... Or even a mild reheating with a heat gun applied to the GPU, once the heatsink has been removed, could fix the issue.

If performing the latter, then construct a heat mask out of heavy duty silver foil with a hole cut just for the GPU, in order to protect the other nearby components from the ravages of the heat gun.

---

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> In order to access the edges of the LCD panel, you need to remove the front panel first:

1. Remove the RAM door (two Philips screws)
2. Remove four Torx screws from the base of the front panel
3. Slide a credit card in to both sides of the slot at the rear, to release the two latches holding the top of the front of the panel
4. Gently loosen the front panel all of the way around but do **not** pull it away fully.
5. Disconnect the camera and microphone cables at the top center
6. Now, you can lever off the front panel

See the first three minutes of [How to Replace a Hard Drive in a 2006/2007 White iMac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOQ3joWnU-s) for a clear demonstration of how to remove the front panel.

Comment: Thanks Greenonline. Are you suggesting that the GPU may have some cold solder joints and that is why I am getting the line artifacts? It seems at first boot, there are none, then they start to show. Perhaps some new thermal paste and re-seating of the GPU could help? I don't know where to locate the GPU, do you?

Comment: Yes, it may need reflowing/reballing. Maybe there are dendrites that have grown between the solder balls (not sure, but possible). Applying new thermal paste is unlikely to fix the issue (unless there is overheating), but you could try it. See [Is it possible to replace the GPU in this 2006 iMac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/333353/100490). The GPU is at the bottom right of the motherboard, the other, slightly above to the left, is the CPU.

Comment: This *may* help, [How to change graphics card of white iMac 24" (model September 2006)](http://dufters.de/Alfred/iMac24ChangeGraphics/index.html) - lots of info and photos However, as yours is the 17" there will be some obvious differences. However, I would still check the edges of the LCD first, as the LCD warms up the connections might start loosening - but this is unusual, normally the lines should be static. To re-cap, from the photo it looks like an LCD issue, rather than a GPU. However, from your text description (moving lines) is sounds like possibly GPU (or a warming LCD).